# Register some hotkeys when LCD is off

Tags: windows, winapi, autohotkey

I am using AutoHotKey and I want few hotkeys to work only if LCD is off (i.e. the black screen with no power). How, Can I do this? I found some similar code on http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/92463-laptop-screen-open-screen-shut-hotkey/ but because of not expertise with Windows API I am not able to tweak it to match my needs.

Comment: Under which conditions is your monitor off?

Comment: @MCL When I close the lid. See Control Panel->Power Options->Choose What closing thee lid do

Comment: Have you checked out [LidWatcher](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/92888-lidwatcher-monitor-the-state-of-your-laptop-lid/)?

Comment: How are you generating hotkeys with the lid closed?